# How to write to proc large amount of data

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I wrote a kernel module that exports some amount of data to a proc entry created. If the amount of data is less, I could easily create a proc entry and export data. But if the amount of data is large, it gives buffer overflow error.

I used the function `int read_proc(char *buf,char **start,off_t offset,int count, int *eof, void *data)` to export data. And I wrote the data like:

```
    length =sprintf(buf,"The RESTART_SYSCALL address is %x\n",syscall_table[__NR_restart_syscall]);
    length +=sprintf(buf+length,"The EXIT address is %x\n",syscall_table[__NR_exit]);
    length +=sprintf(buf+length,"The FORK address is %x\n",syscall_table[__NR_fork]);   
    length +=sprintf(buf+length,"The READ address is %x\n",syscall_table[__NR_read]);
    length +=sprintf(buf+length,"The WRITE address is %x\n",syscall_table[__NR_write]);
    length +=sprintf(buf+length,"The OPEN address is %x\n",syscall_table[__NR_open]);
    length +=sprintf(buf+length,"The CLOSE address is %x\n",syscall_table[__NR_close]);
    length +=sprintf(buf+length,"The WAITPID address is %x\n",syscall_table[__NR_waitpid]);
    length +=sprintf(buf+length,"The CREAT address is %x\n",syscall_table[__NR_creat]);
    length +=sprintf(buf+length,"The LINK address is %x\n",syscall_table[__NR_link]);
    length +=sprintf(buf+length,"The UNLINK address is %x\n",syscall_table[__NR_unlink]);
    length +=sprintf(buf+length,"The EXECVE address is %x\n",syscall_table[__NR_execve]);
    length +=sprintf(buf+length,"The TIME address is %x\n",syscall_table[__NR_time]);
    length +=sprintf(buf+length,"The MKNOD address is %x\n",syscall_table[__NR_mknod]);
    length +=sprintf(buf+length,"The LCHOWN address is %x\n",syscall_table[__NR_lchown]);
    length +=sprintf(buf+length,"The BREAK address is %x\n",syscall_table[__NR_break]);
    length +=sprintf(buf+length,"The OLDSTAT address is %x\n",syscall_table[__NR_oldstat]);
    length +=sprintf(buf+length,"The LSEEK address is %x\n",syscall_table[__NR_lseek]);
    length +=sprintf(buf+length,"The GETPID address is %x\n",syscall_table[__NR_getpid]);
-----------------------------------
---------------------------------
---------------------------------
```

I read that by default only one PAGE_SIZE, that is 4kb is exported. I referred the LDD to find how to export large amount of data. But I couldnt understand whats written there. Could anyone help me in this.

Comment: I would look at the implementation of e.g. `/proc/self/maps` or `/proc/vmallocinfo`. They probably write each line one at a time, and maintain some state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "seq file" wrapper (linux/seq_file.h).
This lets you define a callback function that returns one line of data, and Linux calls this callback as many times as needed.
If each line is under 4K, it's quite simple. I'm not sure if it supports larger lines.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [debugfs facilities](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/debugfs.txt) available in the kernel. You can probably export more data than 4k via a file in debugfs.

If this does not help, transfering data via netlink sockets may also be an option for your task.